# Jenkins dsl configure block makes duplicate tabs

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to create a job DSL which creates a multibranch-pipeline job,
The job is being created successfully but there are some missing configurations in the multi-pipeline job so I tried to use the "configure" block.

The configure block indeed was created but it created a duplicate "tag" of **jenkins.branch.BranchSource** I guess I am missing something' I tried tons of manipulations but nothing worked for me.
Any advice?

This is my groovy DSL:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('TestDocker_pipeline_DSL') {     

    branchSources {
        git {
            remote(gitUrl)
            credentialsId('Dev_Builder_ssh')
            //includes("(V[0-9]+.[0-9]+([.]+[0-9]+)*)|(master)")
        }
        configure {
            it / sources / data / "jenkins.branch.BranchSource" << "jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource"  {
                id("8fd33e1d-07b6-4cc4-8f1c-a18d955b4b6e")
                remote(gitUrl)
                credentialsId('Dev_Builder_ssh')
                traits{
                    "jenkins.scm.impl.trait.RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait"{
                        regex("V[0-9]+.[0-9]+([.]+[0-9]+)*)|(master)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    factory {
        workflowBranchProjectFactory {
            scriptPath('main/Docker/DockerJenkinsfileSlave.groovy')
        }
    }
    orphanedItemStrategy {
        discardOldItems {
            numToKeep(3)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the job XML being created:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well After a lot of struggling I think that my problem was that I didn't define some of the **TAGS** as plugins in the groovy DSL and removing the "**git**" section also helped.

So the Final groovy that finally worked was this one:

```
branchSources {
    configure {
        it / sources / data / "jenkins.branch.BranchSource" <<  source (class: "jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource", plugin:"git@3.9.2")  {
            remote(gitUrl)
            credentialsId('Dev_Builder_ssh')
            includes('*')
            excludes('')
            ignoreOnPushNotifications(false)
            traits{
                "jenkins.scm.impl.trait.RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait"{
                    regex("(V[0-9]+.[0-9]+([.]+[0-9]+)*)|(master)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which resulted this beutifull XML job:

[image]

Comment: I had the exact same error, I'm not sure how this is not the most common problem, the Job DSL creates (at least in the latest version) all plugin-specific entries with the versions of the related plugin in the XML, preventing the XML matching tag from finding the right tag, so it silently creates a new one.